# how write a specific format of todays day in external JS

Tags: javascript

How do I write a a date like this Wednesday, February 13 2019 in a external java script file?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "January", "February", "March",
    "April", "May", "June", "July",
    "August", "September", "October",
    "November", "December"
  ];
  
  var dayofweek=[
     "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday",
     "Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];

  var day = date.getDate();  
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();  
  var dowIdx = date.getDay();
 
  return( dayofweek[dowIdx] + ', ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' +day + " " + year);
}

console.log(formatDate(new Date()));
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `Intl.DateTimeFormat()` so that we can utilize the `FormatToParts()` function then apply a custom `map()` then finally `reduce()` to get the desired output.

Within the `map()` function we replace the value of the `literal` after the day value to remove the comma (there by default).

*References at MDN:*

- [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)
- [Date Format Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString#Parameters)
- [Locales Argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl#locales_argument) -- *We are using `undefined` in order to use the user's default*
- [FormatToParts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts)

```js
const d = new Date();

const formatOptions = {
    weekday: 'long',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour12: true
};

// Using Intl.DateTimeFormat so we have access to
//     formatToParts function which produces
//     an Array of objects containing the formatted date in parts
const dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, formatOptions);

// Keep track of 'literal' key counts (`literal` is the separator)
let separatorIndex = 0;

// Where the magic happens using map() and reduce()
const dateString = dateFormat.formatToParts(d).map(({type, value}) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'literal' :
      separatorIndex++;
      
      switch (separatorIndex) {
        case 3 : // Day separator
          return ' ';
        default: return value;
      }
      break;
   default: return value;
  }
})
.reduce((string, part) => {
  return string.concat(part)
});

// Not part of answer; only for output result
document.write(dateString);
```